# Authentication Service redirects to custom url and provide token in query of it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, redirect, token

I am using `url_launcher` to launch an authentication service but it redirects the the user after agreeing with conditions to a custom url (given by developer) where in the query parameter of the redirected url a token or like user personal id is present which I need so how do I get it ? Is there any way to get it without having to make a server which would store the token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to changes in links by the package [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

```
void processLink(String link) {
  // Parse the link and extract the token or user ID in the 'token' parameter
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
  String token = uri.queryParameters['token'];

  print('Token: $token'); //this is the token
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain it to me in more detail ? I get that I can listen to link changes with the help of this package but how will it know when the link changes in streamSubscription ?

Comment: first
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final String authUrl = 'your_authentication_service_url';
final String customUrl = 'your_custom_redirect_url';

launch(authUrl);

void initUniLinks() async {
  try {
    String initialLink = await getInitialLink();
    processLink(initialLink);

    getLinksStream().listen((String link) {
      processLink(link);
    });
  } on PlatformException {
    // Handle exception
  }
}

and then call initUniLinks in your app initialization code
initUniLinks();